# How to autowire services outside of the constructor?

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to add `@Autowired` to a class, and also add a constructor to that class that does not use these autowired classes?

Example:

```
public class MyJob {
    @Autowired
    private MyService1 serv1;

    @Autowired
    private MyService2 serv2;

    public MyJob(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }
}
```

Here I want to take `MyService1` and `MyService2` for granted, and just initialize those class `@Bean` by using the constructor:

```
@Bean
public getMyJob1() {
    return new MyJob("test1");
}

@Bean
public getMyJob2() {
    return new MyJob("test2");
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Note that you'd be effectively creating a plain Java class with members that can be only instantiated via reflection (i.e. cannot live without Spring), making it tricky to test it. Why not inject the services via the constructor?

Comment: Because, imagine I want to create multiple `@Bean`s pb `MyJob`, and they only differ by filename. Then I'd have to add any required services always inside the constructor, even though they are always the same.

Comment: I'd use a setter for the `filename` property

Comment: And that is an issue why? It is clear, concise and leaves no magic. Currently you have explicitly defined a single constructor but require 2 additional beans, which get injected by some magic some how, which is not really clear to the user of your class. You  might want to read this http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to make a Factory for the MyJob's instances:

```
public class MyJobFactory {
    private MyService1 serv1;    
    private MyService2 serv2;

    @Autowired
    public MyJobFactory(MyService1 serv1, MyService2 serv2) {
        this.serv1 = serv1;
        this.serv2 = serv2;
    }

    public MyJob myJob(String filename) {
        return new MyJob(filename, serv1, serv2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I could agree if you would use constructor injection for both dependencies :).

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply use a setter for the `filename` property:

```
public class MyJob {
    @Autowired
    private MyService1 serv1;

    @Autowired
    private MyService2 serv2;

    private String filename;

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    // getter for filename
}
```

And then, in the factory class:

```
@Bean
public MyJob getMyJob1() {
    MyJob job = new MyJob();
    job.setFilename("test1");
    return job;
}

@Bean
public MyJob getMyJob2() {
    MyJob job = new MyJob();
    job.setFilename("test2");
    return job;
}
```

Comment: I would say this is even worse, the `filename` is required for proper functioning. Required properties should be injected through the constructor, so that you cannot create an object in an invalid state.

Comment: @M.Deinum That is too puristic. In this case, both `MyJob` instances are being created and *initialized* in a factory class (via `@Bean` methods). As in almot everything, the simpler, the better

Comment: And you have a public class with a public constructor which doesn't prevent anyone from instantiating that class outside your factory. It has nothing to do with purism it is about design and adhering to OO rules/principals.

Comment: @M.Deinum if you are using Spring, nobody should instantiate classes. That's what Spring does. If you do, you should only do it in factory classes.

Comment: The fact that you use spring still doesn't mean you shouldn't do proper OO and follow the same principals. No framework forces you into that, and when unit testing you are creating your bean instances not spring (else you aren't doing a unit test but an integration test).

Comment: @M.Deinum I promise this is my last comment. While you have a valid point regarding good OO principles and Spring, a factory that creates a factory that finally creates the desired instances is not good OO design, but overengineering. OO design is not about being perfect, but about doing things simple.